# Transparent UINavigationBar without border

Tags: ios, swift

With iOS 7, it's now pretty easy to add a blur to UINavigationBar, even with a BarTint, see http://blog.ashleynh.me/frosted-uinavigationbar/ and this example image:

[image]

However, there's a border at the bottom. How can I get rid of the border to look more like this?

[image]

**UPDATE**:

I took Danny and Shali's code, and here are the results. As you can see, the border doesn't show any more but there is no blur.

```
let navigationBarAppearance = UINavigationBar.appearance()
navigationBarAppearance.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
navigationBarAppearance.shadowImage = UIImage()
navigationBarAppearance.translucent = true
```

[image]

and here's the Inspector screenshot:

[image]

I also tried:

```
let navigationBarAppearance = UINavigationBar.appearance()
let clearImage = UIImage.imageWithColor(UIColor.clearColor())
navigationBarAppearance.setBackgroundImage(clearImage, forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
navigationBarAppearance.shadowImage = clearImage
navigationBarAppearance.translucent = true
```

Same result, but the Inspector is a little different:

[image]

Comment: You don't need the status bar at the top, which has time, battery status etc?

Comment: Not really. Although that's pretty easily changeable with:     `override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }`

Answer (score 1):

Apple Documents: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationBar/shadowImage

> The default value is nil, which corresponds to the default shadow
>   image. When non-nil, this property represents a custom shadow image to
>   show instead of the default. **For a custom shadow image to be shown, a
>   custom background image must also be set with the
>   setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics: method.** If the default background
>   image is used, then the default shadow image will be used regardless
>   of the value of this property.

So basically you need to set background image before setting shadowImage to make it work.

**Edit**

Image generated from color (Swift) as background Navigation.  Not sure if your blur function will still work when you change backgroundImage for Navigation bar. That would be a different problem.

```
class func imageWithColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
    let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0)
    color.setFill()
    UIRectFill(rect)
    var image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return image
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shali, What would I need to set the `ShadowImage` to be? I want the image underneath the `UINavigationBar` to show through, so `UINavigationBar` doesn't know what that image is.

Comment: @Dean If you want to hide the line, just do as Danny said.  It you want the image to see through, you can draw a image with clear color.  I will append the function for image generating from color.

Comment: Thanks Shali. PS., love the extension code for `UIImage`. I set translucent on, set barTint to nil, and `ShadowImage` to `UIImage` with `UIColor.clearColor()`, The BackImage and BackMask still says `Empty Selection`. I get the same result as with `.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)` and `.shadowImage = UIImage()`.

Comment: @Dean what do you mean by empty selection?

Comment: In Xcode Inspector, I see that. Let me update my question with screenshots.

Comment: @Dean  yeah, actually when you only need background to be clear, it's not necessary to generate image with clear color. UIImage() is fine.  Only if you need a bit color.  For back image, I think it doesn't mean background, it means back button?  You may need to select another area for check background image.   I have something here which has class name as UINavigationBarBackground.

Comment: I think you are right Shali. BackImage turns out to be the back button's image. Ugh naming! Let me try ShadowImage with a color with Alpha...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new]; ?

Comment: I also tried `.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)`, that gets rid of the border, but there's no blur.

Comment: I set `.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.2)` and `.translucent = true` and I verified in Inspector that that's correct. `ShowImage`, `BackImage`, and `BackMask` are all `Empty Selection`